# Series convergence of $\sum_1^\infty{|a_n|}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is there anyway to prove that the series $\sum_1^\infty{|a_n|}$ must be convergent if (1) $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$ and (2) it is bounded. Could anyone give me an counterexample if not?

An example of that being true is $\sum_1^\infty{\frac{\sin{(4n)}}{4^n}}$

Comment: Let $b_k := \sum_{1}^k |a_n|$. Then $b_k$ is a monotone sequence that is bounded above, and thus converges.

Comment: You don't need (1), it is implied by (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $\left(\sum_{n=1}^N|a_n|\right)_{N\in\mathbb N}$ is clearly a non-decreasing sequence. If it is also bounded, then it is convergent (every monotonic bounded sequence of real numbers converges).